# Serving files with user restrictions with Django

Tags: django, django-views

I need help with this one. In my application users are connected with projects. Let's say I want to enable download of files just for user if has `created_by` field in `file` model equal to `request.user`.

How is that possible. Is there any generic view or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to the model that can be used in the view. Something like this:

```
class File:
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # NOTE other fields go here...

    def is_downloadable_by_user(self, request):
        return self.created_by == request.user
```

Then in your view you can do something like this:

```
# NOTE fix import based on project configuration
import File

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    # NOTE get file instance however you want
    file = File(id=1)
    if file.is_downloadable_by_user():
        # DO SOMETHING
```

With some tweaks, I imagine this approach should work for you. The `@login_required` is a [default Django decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#s-the-login-required-decorator).